# Changing a list into an array to calculate grade averages etc

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I have to create a program that uses an array in one method to take a users input of student grades. Then, in another method, I have to take those grades and calculate the minimum, maximum, average, etc.

***PLEASE KEEP IN MIND I am still a beginner at java.***

----------I have figured out the menu problem:
--- I am also having problems getting the menu to work correctly. It needs to print out and repeat until the user types 5, to exit. -

Edited coding:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of students: ");
    int numStudents = keyboard.nextInt();

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int total = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<numStudents; i++){
        System.out.println("Please enter the grade of student" + (i+1));
        int grade = keyboard.nextInt();
        max = Math.max(max, grade);
        min = Math.min(min, grade);
        total += grade;
    }
    double average = total/numStudents;
    //menu here//

    System.out.println("Please choose form the following options: ");

    System.out.println("1- Display minimum grade");
    System.out.println("2- Display maximum grade");
    System.out.println("3- Display average");
    System.out.println("4- Display the standard deviation");
    System.out.println("5- Exit");

    System.out.print("-> ");
    int menu = keyboard.nextInt();


        if(menu==1)
        {
        System.out.println("The maximum grade is: " + max);
        }

        if(menu==2)
        {    
        System.out.println("The minimum grade is: " + min);
        }
        if(menu==3)
        {
        System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
        }
        if(menu==4)
        {    
        System.out.println("The standard deviation is: ");
        }
        if(menu==5)
        {
        System.out.println("Exit");
        }

       do{
           System.out.println("Please choose form the following options: ");

    System.out.println("1- Display minimum grade");
    System.out.println("2- Display maximum grade");
    System.out.println("3- Display average");
    System.out.println("4- Display the standard deviation");
    System.out.println("5- Exit");

    System.out.print("-> ");
    int menu1 = keyboard.nextInt();
     if(menu==1)
        {
        System.out.println("The maximum grade is: " + max);
        }

        if(menu1==2)
        {    
        System.out.println("The minimum grade is: " + min);
        }
        if(menu1==3)
        {
        System.out.println("The average is: " + average);
        }
        if(menu1==4)
        {    
        System.out.println("The standard deviation is: ");
        }
        if(menu1==5)
        {
        System.out.println("Exit");
        return;
        }
       }while(menu!=5);
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've got it working (except for the Standard Deviation part) but your code is a bit redundant. You're printing out the menu twice, which isn't necessary.

Perhaps create a method like:

```
public static int printMenu()
    {
        System.out.println("Please choose form the following options: ");

        System.out.println("1- Display minimum grade");
        System.out.println("2- Display maximum grade");
        System.out.println("3- Display average");
        System.out.println("4- Display the standard deviation");
        System.out.println("5- Exit");

        System.out.print("-> ");
        return 0;
    }
```

And then reformat your conditional statements with a while loop, something like:

```
 while (menu != 5)
 {
     if(menu==1)
     {
        System.out.println("The maximum grade is: " + max);
     }
     if(menu==2)

     ...


     printMenu();
     menu = keyboard.nextInt();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using java, try to address this scenario with OOP concepts. It will be very easy to solve this system if you want more clarifications inform me.

Create class as Student or something with getter and setter methods.

then seperate your minimum,maximum,average logics into different class.

it will be a clear way.

Comment: I am a beginner at programming, and have no idea what this means. Thanks though.

Comment: [link](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-oops-concepts)   you can learn very basic OOP concepts from ths link

Comment: I am not quite sure what any of that really means. All I know is my professor is specific in the fact of how he wants us to program this.

Answer (score 0):

There is redundancy in your code.You did not have to write the menu twice.
moreover you need to use System.exit(0) to exit your program ,not return.
And in your while condition should be(menu1!=0),but you have written (menu!=0) instead .
You can also use a break statement instead.